# i tried a html code for next and previous 5 years in a drop down.. i got next 5 years properly.. how can i get previous 5 years

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

i tried a html code for next and previous 5 years in a drop down.. i got next 5 years properly.. how can i get previous 5 years

please he;p me with the code

```
function populatedropdown(yearfield){
var today=new Date()
var yearfield=document.getElementById(yearfield)
var thisyear=today.getFullYear()
for (var y=0; y<5; y++){
yearfield.options[y]=new Option(thisyear, thisyear)
thisyear+=1
}
yearfield.options[0]=new Option(today.getFullYear(), today.getFullYear(), true, true) //select today's year
}

</script>
  </head>
  <body>
<form action="" name="someform">
<select id="yeardropdown">
</select> 
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

//populatedropdown(id_of_day_select, id_of_month_select, id_of_year_select)
window.onload=function(){
populatedropdown("yeardropdown")
}
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
function populatedropdown(yearfield) {
  var today = new Date(),
      yearfield = document.getElementById(yearfield),
      beforeYears = 3
      afterYears = 5,
      thisyear = today.getFullYear();
  
  for (var year = thisyear-beforeYears, index = 0; 
           index <= beforeYears + afterYears; 
           index++, year++) {
    yearfield.options[index] = new Option(year, year);
  }
  yearfield.value = thisyear;
    //select today's year
}

//populatedropdown(id_of_day_select, id_of_month_select, id_of_year_select)
window.onload = function() {
  populatedropdown("yeardropdown")
}
```

```html
<form action="" name="someform">
  <select id="yeardropdown">
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks its working...... but if it is possible to specify how many years need to be in drop down backword and frond words.. for eg. 3 years befor 5 years  after..

Comment: @Anoop, now that you have the logic it should be easy to do yourself.. but i updated the code anyway..

Comment: @anoop make the relevant `option` have its `disabled` property set to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

try to change for loop should execute -5 to 5

```
for (var y=0; y<5 && y>(-5); y++){
yearfield.options[y]=new Option(thisyear, thisyear)
thisyear+=1
}
```